# Get sheet name by column name

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas

Suppose i have a workbook with mutiple sheets like[sheet1,sheet2,sheet3,sheet4],I want to get a sheet which is having a column name ['comp'],suppose 'sheet3' is having a column name ,So i want sheet name by columnname and pass it to :-read_excel(filename,sheet='sheet3')
the code i tried so far

```
    book = pd.ExcelFile(filename)
for sheet in book.sheet_names:
    df = book.parse(sheet)
    if 'comp' in df.columns:
        book_2=pd.pivot_table(book,values='comp',index=['os_de','sev'], columns=book.comp.values, aggfunc='count')
        book_2
```

### i am able to get the sheet name but not able to do the further process,any approach how should i do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following (assuming this column appear in only one sheet) -

```
book = pd.ExcelFile(filename)
for sheet in book.sheet_names:
    df = book.parse(sheet)
    if col in df.columns:
       return df
return None
```

See documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelFile.parse.html)

Comment: but in furthur approach i am getting error AttributeError: 'ExcelFile' object has no attribute

Comment: can yo help in this